# How are turbostratic graphite phases formed?

Tags: solid-state-chemistry, carbon-allotropes

Turbostratic graphite is graphite in which there is quenched rotational disalignment between adjacent graphene sheets, i.e. one sheet is rotated with respect to its neighbor. I suppose this could be considered a crystallographic defect of sorts. How do these turbostratic layers form, and can they possess long range order, such as glide or helical symmetry (e.g. similar to a twisted nematic phase)?

Answer (score 2):

"High-temperature phase transformation and low friction behaviour in highly disordered turbostratic graphite," doi:10.1088/0022-3727/46/39/395305

"Phase Transformation Mechanism of Graphite-Turbostratic Graphite in the Course of Mechanical Grinding," CHEM. RES. CHINESE U. 19(2), 216 (2003)

http://www.onxlti.com/product-divisions/contract-manufacturing-products/on-x-pyrolytic-carbon/

Comment: Al, this is a good answer to the question, but could you elaborate a bit about what's in the papers?